# How does Discord get Overwatch 2 player status from battle.net APIs?

Tags: api, discord

Discord uses battle.net integration and displays player status such as "Playing Overwatch 2". I looked through battle.net API documentation and couldn't find an API that would provide such data.

Is it using some private APIs?

Comment: Discord shows "Playing [game name]" for games that are not on Battle.net too, so are you sure this is a Battle.net integration, or could it be just checking for games in the current running processes? Are you trying to do something similar in your own game? If so, try editing your question to ask "How can **I**..." instead. We might not know exactly how Discord does it without decompiling it, but that won't stop folks from suggesting ways that could work for you.

Answer (score 2):

First, as indicated in the comments, the "Playing [game name]" status is not unique to Overwatch 2. Discord can look at the client side processes, match them against a database & update the reported status accordingly.

Second, it is possible for an application to integrate with Discord. They provide a dedicated [GameSDK](https://discord.com/developers/docs/game-sdk/sdk-starter-guide) in their [developer documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro).

So it isn't that Discord is using the various APIs of various games, but that games are able to use the Discord API to make use of Discord's features.